# pdf2txt -t xml equivalent in python

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I'm trying to replicate the command line instruction
"pdf2txt -t xml samplePdf.pdf > test.xml" in python:
with this code here:

```
import pdfminer.high_level
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

laparams = LAParams()
laparams.all_texts = True

with open("out.xml", 'w') as out:
  with open('./samplePdf.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
    pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(
      pdf, out, 'xml', codec="", laparams=laparams)
```

The result is similar, But there are some fewer/more textboxes and/or texlines and I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
For example I am trying with the pdf of this scientific article:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00327.pdf
The first difference I notice is that from the command line
the first line that comes out is:
`<? xml version = "1.0"?>`
without mention of coding.
While using python code it is specified: encoding = "utf-8".
But in any case I can't put in encodings since an error of value is also reported for "utf-8". As demonstrated in the code, I must remain the blank value.

Comment: Can you provide an input pdf to make a [mcve]?

Comment: Certainly and sorry if I hadn't already done so. I made an edit.